# solve: $ \frac {d^2y}{dx^2} + 5\frac{dy}{dx} = 15x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac {d^2y}{dx^2} + 5\frac{dy}{dx} = 15x^2 $$

It's solution is

$$y = y_{h} + y_{p}$$

where $y_{h} $ is the solution for homogenous equation and $y_{p} $ is the particular solution

For homogenous solution:
It's auxiliary equation is

$$m^2 + 5m = 0$$

on solving for m,

$$m = 0, -5$$

so, $$y_{h} = C_{1} + C_{2} e^{-5x}$$

here

$$R = 15x^2$$

so it's particular solution should be :

$$y_{p} = K_{2}x^2 + k_{1}x + k_{0}$$

on differentiating with respect to x

$$y\prime _{p}= 2xk_{2} + k_{1}$$

again

$$y\prime\prime_{p} = 2k_{2}$$

using all above values in the initial equation gives

$$2k_{2} + 10xk_{2} + 10k_{1} = 15x^2$$

But using this method I am unable to proceed for the value of all unknown especially $k_{0}$

The given answer is:

$$y = C_{1} + C_{2}e^{-5x} + x^3 + \frac{3x^2}{5} - \frac{6}{25}x$$

Comment: Choose $k_0$ at your desire: any additive constant will vanish on the left hand side of the given equation.

Comment: @fwd for terms $x^n , y_{p} = K_{n} x^n + k_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ..... k_{0}$ isn't it?

Comment: you're right @AbhilekhGautam.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Notice the proposed equation is equivalent to a first order ODE:
\begin{align*}
y'' + 5y' = 15x^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow y' + 5y = 5x^{3} + c_{0}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \exp(5x)y' + 5\exp(5x)y = 5\exp(5x)x^{3} + c_{0}\exp(5x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow [\exp(5x)y]' = 5\exp(5x)x^{3} + c_{0}\exp(5x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \exp(5x)y = 5\int\exp(5x)x^{3}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{c_{0}}{5}\exp(5x) + c_{1}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y = 5\exp(-5x)\int\exp(5x)x^{3}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{c_{0}}{5} + c_{1}\exp(-5x)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I can do this from here, Cannot it be done in the way I did it?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is a just a matter of preference. But I advise you to integrate once before tackling the problem. In general, if you have an equation of the form $y' + ay = P(x)$, where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ and $a\neq 0$, then one particular solution is also a polynomial of degree $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} + 5\frac{dy}{dx} = 15x^2$$
$$v' + 5v = 15x^2$$
Where $v=y'$-

Try $v_p=Ax^2+Bx+C$ for the particular solution.

Comment: Thank you @Fakemistake .................